# FullCalendar does not apply css on changeView in Vaadin framework

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm building a calendar plugin for Vaadin (see https://vaadin.com/). Everythng works fine, the stylesheets are applied EXCEPT when I programatically change the view. The view changes but the Fullcalendar styles do not apply correctly! See sample screenshot.[List View after changeView called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoM1w.jpg)

I need to hit refresh for the styles to apply correctly.

(If I just change the view using the full calendar 'built in' buttons at the top right, the styles are applied.)
Using FullCalendar V3.7.0 and and Scheduler trial 1.9.0

Vaadin is a GWT framework,  using V6.8.

GWT code for calling changeView:

```
private native void changeView(JavaScriptObject cal,String view,String nid) 
/*-{
    cal.fullCalendar("changeView",view);
    //cal.trigger( "create" ); trying to fix the not-applying .css problem
}-*/;
```

'cal' is the original selector returned by jQuery. 
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was due to the Vaadin framework removing FC's style class from the topmost element. To fix, I simply added these back using the framework's setStyleName("fc fc-unthemed fc-ltr");.